# PHP Form Validation - Put it on the form or separate validation file with session variables?

Tags: php, html

I wish to ask whether I should put the PHP validation on the same HTML form, or a seperate file with session variables to display errors when I use header() to redirect to the form page if there are errors.

The main **problem** with putting them into session variables is that those errors stay even when closing the tab and coming back to the form (the browser has to close to reset). If there is a fresh page, then there are errors saying that the session array is empty.

```
<?php session_start() ?>
<!doctype html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="formprocess.php" method="POST">
            <h1>Register For An Account!</h1></br>
            <?php echo $_SESSION['usernameerr']; ?>
            <p>Username: </p><input type="text" name="username"></br></br>
            <?php echo $_SESSION['passworderr']; ?>
            <p>Password: </p><input type="text" name="password"></br></br>
            <?php echo $_SESSION['emailerr']; ?>
            <p>E-mail Address</p><input type="text" name="email"></br></br>
            <input type="submit" name="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

This is the php validation code:

```
<?php
session_start();
/*
 * VALIDATING FORM DATA
 */

// Setting validation variables and functions
$username = $password = $email = "";
$usernameerr = $passworderr = $emailerr = "";

function data_get($param){
    if(isset($_POST[$param])){
        $param = $_POST[$param];
    }
    return $param;
}

function sanitize_data($string){
    $sanitized_string = trim($string);
    $sanitized_string = strip_tags($sanitized_string);
    $sanitized_string = htmlspecialchars($sanitized_string);
    $sanitized_string = stripslashes($sanitized_string);
    return $sanitized_string;
}

// Validation of form data
if(data_get("Submit")){
    //Username validation
    if(empty(data_get("username")) || strlen(data_get("username"))>50){
        $usernameerr = "Please enter a valid username that is less than 50 characters long";
        $_SESSION['usernameerr'] = $usernameerr;
    }
    else{
        $username = sanitize_data(data_get("username"));
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    }

    //Password validation
    if(empty(data_get("password")) || strlen(data_get("username")) > 50){
        $passworderr = "Please enter a valid password that is less than 50 characters long";
        $_SESSION['passworderr'] = $passworderr;
    }
    else{
        $password = password_hash(sanitize_data(data_get("password")), PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
    }

    //Email validation
    if(!filter_var(data_get("email"), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $emailerr = "Please enter a valid email";
        $_SESSION['emailerr'] = $emailerr;
    }
    else{
        $email = filter_var(data_get("email"), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    }
}

//Redirects to database handler
    if(empty($usernameerr) and empty($passworderr) and empty($emailerr)){
        header("Location: dbconn.php");
        exit;
    }
    else{
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Also, did I handle the password encryption correctly? Or am I missing something very important that could hamper security? If everything went okay, I did a `header()` to the `dbconn.php` which would insert that into the database.

EDIT: By the way, I know I haven't added any regular expression checks, which I will add later on. This is just a test validation, and I plan on adding that later.

Comment: Wait. You should use both AJAX and form submit to validate the form, isn't it?

Comment: I don't know if that is how it's supposed to be done, I'm pretty new to PHP, so I don't know AJAX at all.

Comment: Then start learning PHP & AJAX, before you write a lot of scripts & don't know how to use them

Comment: But I'm pretty sure PHP is only required to validate form data (AJAX can also be used I guess). From what I learned, PHP can be used for server-side validation of form data. I don't know how me learning AJAX has anything to do with the question though, as PHP can also be used. Maybe tell me why AJAX should be used over PHP though?

Comment: it's a very bad practice to use only server-side / client-side to perform form validation, as server maybe vulnerable to form attacks. AJAX prevents some simple attempts and keeps server less busy.